# RS485 Trancievers: ADM2483 VS ISO15

Tags: circuit-design, rs485, component-selection

i'm actually doing some hardware selection about RS485 trancievers. There are a lot of different suppliers, drivers, etc...

So, i've selected these two trancievers: [ADM2483](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm2483.pdf) from Analog Devices and [ISO15](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso15.pdf?ts=1593260993514&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) from Texas Instruments.

They seems rugged enough to be used in a harsh and noisy industrial environment, basically my decision is to go for an isolated solution in order to mitigate those problems, my MCU is an ESP32 (so USART levels are 3.3V) and i can supply without any problem 3.3V and 5V.

There is a specific reason to go between one and the other?
There is a distinguishable difference?

I'm planning to go for the ISO15, because between the two, the datasheet says:

*"These devices are ideal for longtransmission lines, because the ground loop is broken to allow for a much larger common-mode voltage range. The symmetrical barrier of the device is tested to provide isolation of 4000VPK per VDE and 2500VRMS per UL and CSA between the bus-line transceiver and the logic-level interface."*

Is that only marketing or it's really optimized for that conditions?

Comment: The ADM2483 has also identical 2500V RMS UL rating and same 560V VIORM VDE rating. CSA rating is diffenent though. Both have same loading (256 devices, or 1/8 loading). Both work at 3.3V IO supply as ESP32 uses that. Same marketing talk applies to ADM2483 as well, ground loop is broken and high common mode is allowed.

Comment: So all in all they are the same?

Comment: It's hard to say, because we can't know what you need. For example one is rated for 500 kbps, other is rated for 1 Mbps. If you have a list of specifications you need to meet, then each item can be compared if it fulfills it or not, and if it exceeds it or not. For example, price. Sometimes, a better or cheaper part on paper might in practice need some workarounds or external parts, so it may not be easier to use or cheaper in total.

Comment: I don't have price constraints, also design of additional components is not a problem, what I need is a robust tranceiver that can survive in harsh and noisy environment...many times is needed to work in buses that doesn't have ground connected between tranceiver and slaves and with a lot of noise (motors, welding machine, etc...)

Comment: Remember that even if the tranceivers bus side is isolated, the bus lines A and B still need to be within the common mode range of the bus side ground - i.e. -7 to +12 V. It can't work properly with only two bus wires A and B, especially because bus is floating without reference, you need to set the bus reference with the third common reference wire, i.e. bus ground. So if it has to work with two bus wires only, you don't have much use for isolation, as the bus ground reference usually is coming from mains plug earth ground pin on each two-pin bus device.

Comment: Yes, I know, in fact this is a common mistake...and I encounter it very frequently! In any case, suppose that we have common ground between the master and all slaves, which can be better for those industrial noisy environment?